# UIImagePickerController intermittently stops responding after tapping "Use" button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that records video. The app is a mixture of cocos2d and UIKit though the part using the UIImagePickerController is all UIKit.

The Problem:
After taking a video, when you tap the "Use" button, the button changes to selected state and then nothing happens. The "Retake" button is disabled. You can still Play/Pause the video but the view never dismisses and `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` is never called.

The problem happens on long and short (<5 second) videos. Causing memory warnings did not reproduce the issue. Changing audio sessions before launching the image picker did not reproduce the issue either.

I have been unable to cause the issue. It happens only occasionally. Any ideas?

Here is the code that presents the UIImagePickerController

```
  UIImagePickerController *tmpVC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  tmpVC.delegate = self;
  tmpVC.allowsEditing = YES;
  // First get the right media types for the right source
  NSArray *types = nil;
  if (useCamera)
  {
    types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    tmpVC.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  }
  else
  {
    types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    tmpVC.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  }

  // Then see if "movie" is in there
  for (NSString *mediaType in types)
  {
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
      tmpVC.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie,nil];
      tmpVC.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    }
  }

  // Present the configured controller
  [self presentModalViewController:tmpVC animated:YES];
  [tmpVC release];
```

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in an app that is only UIKit, but only on one (iOS 5) device; another (iOS 4) works fine.

Comment: Since your question is not very details and only 1 snippet of code is showing, I will comment instead of answer. "occasionally" suggests that it has to do with threading (mannual or automatic). One thing I would try is removing this line `[tmpVC release];`. Another thing is, make sure that delegate is set correctly. Look into `imagePickerController` and put a log/breakpoint. Then step through what happens in debug. If you would like more specific answer, you need to be more detail on your question.

Comment: If you could share the project, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing the app in the Simulator? Try testing it on a device and see if it does the same. I remember that I had a similar problem where I couldn't select a video with the picker in the Simulator because the application will just get "stuck" after I pressed the Use button.

Answer (score 1):

I would look else where in your code, is it called in a if statement? Did you alloc and init the thing that calls the - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info. Those are just some little things I would look for, plus call a NSLog() where you see the call the function to know it has been called or there could be an error there.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of my problem was that in iOS 5,

```
[picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

no longer works - `parentViewController` is nil. Confusingly, this causes the picker view to be "finished" but not dismissed, and it just remains inactive.

Instead, you can use:

```
[picker.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

But this doesn't work in iOS 4, as there is no `presentingViewController` message.

You can either write a category that automatically picks the right one, or keep a reference to the view controller that presented it manually. For example in my case the delegate was also the view controller which presented it, so I was able to do

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

In my selector.